# How to add minutes to a DATE type using only to_char and to_date?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As mentioned in title, I am looking for way to add minutes onto a DATE type attribute without converting it to another data type.

```
( SELECT to_char(event_starttime, 'HH:MI:SS') + to_char('00:06:44', 'HH:MI:SS')
FROM
    event
WHERE
    event_id = (
        SELECT
            event_id
        FROM
            event
        WHERE
                carn_date = to_date((
                    SELECT
                        carn_date
                    FROM
                        carnival
                    WHERE
                        carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022'
                ), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            AND eventtype_code = '21K'
    )
);
```

But it does not seem to be working. Converting to other data type is not possible and I can only use to_char and to_date to do it.

Once again, thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you not want to convert to another type? Isn't the result the only import thing, not the way you get it?

Comment: it is a requirement from school

Comment: Hint: Google INTERVAL syntax to add minutes.

Comment: Using `to_char` and `to_date` *is* converting to a different data type. It's a bit unclear what you're doing, or why. The date data type always includes a time, even if it is midnight. Is the `event_starttime` currently set to midnight, and you're trying to set the time portion to something else? Or it's already non-midnight and you want to adjust it (which could take it to the next day)? Or something else? (Either is *possible* using those functions, but would be a strange approach.)

Answer (score 2):

To add, for example, 15 minutes to a date just do this:

```
select event_starttime + (1/1440*15) from event;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Converting to other data type is not possible
> I can only use to_char and to_date to do it

Those two statements are contradictory. `to_date()` converts from a string data type to to a date data type; `to_char()` does the reverse.

But lets assume the second one is your actual requirement, and the assignment is not to use other functions like `to_dsinterval()` or other data types like intervals - however arbitrary a restriction that is.

If the starting date has its time set to midnight then you can convert just the date portion to a string, append the new time also still as a string, and convert the result to a date:

```
to_date(to_char(event_starttime, 'YYYY-MM-DD ') || '00:06:44', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Whether the starting date has its time as midnight or not, you can convert your time to a fraction of a day and add that; but that involves `sysdate` and `trunc()` as well as the two functions you mentioned:

```
event_starttime + (to_date('00:06:44', 'HH24:MI:SS') - trunc(sysdate, 'MM'))
```

That works because if you omit the date elements, `to_date()` gives you the specified time on the first day of the current month. And `trunc(sysdate, 'MM')` gives you midnight on that same day. Subtracting them gives you the fraction of a day that your time represents, which can then just be added to the original date, whatever time it already has.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b68c10235862f418fce5bd5128a50712) showing both, with the intermediate values so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `TO_DATE` and `TO_CHAR` as that is converting it to another data-type (`TO_CHAR` converts the date to a string and `TO_DATE` converts a string to a date). Instead, add an `INTERVAL` to the `DATE` which will result in another `DATE` value (and an unchanged data-type):

```sql
SELECT event_starttime + INTERVAL '00:06:44' HOUR TO SECOND
FROM   event
WHERE  event_id = ( SELECT event_id
                    FROM   event
                    WHERE  carn_date =  SELECT TRUNC(carn_date)
                                        FROM   carnival
                                        WHERE  carn_name = 'RM Autumn Series Caulfield 2022'
                                      )
                    AND eventtype_code = '21K'
                  )
```

If you do not see a difference then change the preferences for how SQL Developer displays dates using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```